# How to make sequence number from attribute class Div which have random number with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, numbers, sequence

I have a `div` like this:

```
<div id="masterDiv">
  <div id="childDiv" class="3" ></div>
  <div id="childDiv" class="5" ></div>
  <div id="childDiv" class="10" ></div>
</div>
```

How can I make value from attribute `class` become sequence number when clicked?  Like this:

```
<div id="masterDiv">
  <div id="childDiv" class="1" ></div>
  <div id="childDiv" class="2" ></div>
  <div id="childDiv" class="3" ></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a quick pointer:

[what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names

Comment: When you give elements an id attribute, it should be unique.

Comment: it just for sample for this question..hihi

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#masterDiv > div").each(function(i, item){
        $(this).attr("class", i + 1);      
    });            
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally id values should be unique. That is the whole purpose of using an id. In your case instead of id make use of multiple class names

```
<div id="masterDiv">
 <div class="childDiv 3" ></div>
 <div class="childDiv 5" ></div>
 <div class="childDiv 10" ></div>
</div>
```

then try this (I've slightly modified Rory's solution)

```
$(".childDiv").each(function(index) {
 $(this).removeClass().addClass(index + 1).addClass("childDiv");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".childDiv").each(function(index) {
    $(this).removeClass().addClass(index);
});
```

Comment: this code will remove the value of attr class. I have found the solve from Mytho. thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Code sample:

```
$("#masterDiv > div").attr("class", function(arr) {return "classname"+arr;})
});
```

Comment: But it will start form zero and you can remove that div which has class with zero index by hasClass

Comment: adjutement ofr zero index class

$("#masterDiv > div").attr("class", function(arr) {return "classname"+(arr+1);})
});